# Error opening xlsx file created by openpyxl using flask

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to write some data into an excel file (using openpyxl) after a user filled out a form created in Flask (WTForms). The data gets written to an excel sheet, but every time, I open the excel file, I get a below error. I am not sure what I need to do to stop that warning from appearing.
[Excel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjhr9.png)

My code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
class MyForm(Form):
    Name = StringField('Name: ', [InputRequired("Please enter your name.")])

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit_form():
    Name = form.Name.data
    workbook = load_workbook(filename='C:\\users\\TestUser\\Desktop\\Test.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.active
    appendData = worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1, value=(Name))
    worksheet.append(appendData)
    workbook.save('C:\\users\\TestUser\\Desktop\\Test.xlsx')
```

Comment: If the error is something to do with the file then I suggest you test just the relevant openpyxl code, which does indeed look wrong: use either `ws.cell` or `ws.append`

Comment: thanks Charlie.
I am using ws.cell and ws.append because I want that everytime a user fills a Name in the form created in Flask, it gets appended to the entries already in the excel file.
I tried using only ws.cell and did not get an error when I opened Excel file, but at the same time, previous values of Name already in the excel file gets erased when new value of Name gets written to the excel file..
So, how we can write Name in the excel file while maintaining whats already in the excel file?
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: My apologizes, but I am very new to flask and openpyxl

Comment: Of course, `ws.cell()` always gets rewritten: the coordinates are always the same!

Answer (score 0):

`worksheet.append([Name])` resolves the issue.

Comment: This is exactly what the openpyxl docs suggest! http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#simple-usage